# Spring Cache Configuration

Tags: spring, caching

This one seems like a simple question. When I attempt to run or compile my maven project in eclipse, I get the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /articleservices threw load() exception
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 73; columnNumber: 32; The prefix "p" for attribute "p:name" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)..
```

Note I truncated the error message since I believe that this root is quite self-explanatory...But no matter how much I look around and check, it doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with my configuration file, which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd        
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mylittlecacheproject" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- annotation caching -->
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Enables aspjectj model -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <!-- Validator -->
    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />


    <!-- Resolve logical view names to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views 
        directory -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="3" />
    </bean>

    <!-- XMLConverter Injection -->
    <bean id="XMLConverter" class="mppiwebservices.utils.xml.XMLConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
        <property name="mappingLocation" value="classpath:rssMapping.xml" />
        <property name="ignoreExtraElements" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- generic cache manager -->
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean"
                    p:name="rsspassthrough" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Okay I'm just too lazy to clip out the other beans used in the project, but my question would be...Am I actually specifying the correct schema location for spring's cache? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found it, in the spring documentation, this namespace `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"`

was not included in the example configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you wanted to write `p:name` in following code?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean" p:name="rsspassthrough" />
```

Comment: well it's how [Spring Documents](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) puts it.

I tried using "name" instead of "p:name" and it throws up a totally different error. So I'm not sure if I'm the only one having this error, Spring's schema isn't updated, or I'm missing something.

Comment: The problem is, there is no namespace defined for `p` (similar to `mvc` or `aop`). You need to check all the schemas where name is a property.